How to keep last few numbers of lines or last few numbers of bytes from each file of folder recursively and save with same name keeping hierarchy
I have logs folder under which there can be nested sub folders. I want to operate on each file recursively and keep last few bytes (tail -c) or last few lines (tail -n) based on configuration and delete existing and keep the updated file with the same name. I want to operate for every file recursively and maintaining hierarchal structure.
Update:
eval "find $TEMP_FOLDER -type f| while read f;do tail -c "${my_array[0]}" $f > ${f}.tmp && mv ${f}.tmp ${f};done"

I have used above. Its working fine.

What did you try, where did you get stuck, how did it fail, and do you have a question? See [ask] then [edit] your question to provide all the missing information that'd allow us to help you (don't reply in a comment).

If you solved your problem, it's better to write an actual answer; you can self-answer your own question just fine. It's clearer then that the problem is solved.

Please format your code properly

This is extremely error-prone. Homebrew log rotation schemes should be replaced by systemd-journald or equivalent. (In XY problem parlance, systemd-journald may be the answer to X.) For example: A process logs into ${f}. It has lines pending in buffers. The tail of ${f} is copied into ${f}.tmp. ${f}.tmp is moved back to ${f}. Questions: (0) How are the pending lines saved? (1) What prevents the process from writing into the (still open) inode behind the former ${f} forever, occupying space until stopped and losing all subsequent output?

A little more elegant (drops the eval and pipe):
for f in $(find $TEMP_FOLDER -type f);do tail -c "${my_array[0]}" $f > ${f}.tmp && mv ${f}.tmp ${f};done


